# Crawlers visiting my cronjobs?

Tags: google-crawlers

I have been building websites for several years now, mostly in php. Several of the sites have cronjobs, that typically run once a day. The php files that the cronjobs run are stored on the server, along with the files that deliver the site pages.

I know that various crawlers, legitimate and not, visit various pages of my sites. Now if a crawler would visit one of my cronjob files, this would activate the cronjob, sometimes with undesirable results.

I'm pretty sure that this has never happened, and, although I'm grateful for that, I'm trying to understand why. Of course there are no links anywhere to any of my cronjob url's, but I'm pretty sure that various crawlers have visited other pages even though they were never linked to.

What do other developers do to address this issue? Put a line in the robots.txt file? Set the permissions of the cronjob-relate php files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't store any cron scripts in a publicly accessible directory.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. Follow-up questions:

1. What should be the exact permissions of the folder that I put my cronjobs in? (What I'm asking for is the 3-digit number.)
2. Could I alternatively set the permissions of the cronjob script file itself, and what permission would I set it to?
3. Finally, could I use robots.txt, or would unscrupulous crawlers ignore that file, and, even worse, exploit it?

Thanks again.

Comment: Well if your storing the script in a non-public directory then the permissions become a little more arbitrary but 644 should be fine.  If you're on a shared server you might want to lock it down a little more but it all depends on what the script does.  If you leave the script in a public directory (just don't) then you could use the robot.txt to tell bots to skip it, but as you've already stated the concern, some crawlers don't give a rat's backend what the robot.txt file states.   Stick the file in a non-public directory, chmod it to 644 and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks again, Jeff. Although your solution would seem to be the best, yet another option would appear to be: if (isset($_SERVER)) {exit();} For existing sites, this might be easier for me -- to move all those cronjobs to a different folder might mean that I'd have to start going into the code and fixing up all folder-relevant portions.

Answer (score 0):

Along with @Jeff's great answer:

The only way a search engine will crawl your page is if there is something linking to it.  This might be another page on your site, a page on someone else's site, or your own sitemap.

Regardless your cron job should never be directly accessible from the outside.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. However, I think I disagree with what you say: I'm pretty sure that on occasion, crawlers and hackers have found pages on my websites that were not linked to from anywhere.

Comment: @oyvey: "crawlers" and "hackers" are two completely different things.  Hackers will try known admin page names to get to your site.  Crawlers on the other hand just follow links.  You might want to read this link for some info on how google (and by extension most search engines) work: http://www.googleguide.com/google_works.html